# Ember.js #link-to transition crazy params

Tags: ember.js

My current url looks like:

```
url/param1/param2
```

I am going through a transition like this:

```
{{#link-to 'oneplace' newParam }}
```

And this transition moves me to:

```
url/param1/newParam
```

But I would like

```
url/newParam/param2
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your router?

Comment: this.resource('oneplace', {path:':param1/:param2'}